# How do I install a built C++ library to /usr/include?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, shared-libraries, point-cloud-library

**Goal**

I would like to install the latest C++ Pointcloud library: [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) release 1.8 on Ubuntu 16.04, and install it in a way such that I can import it in C++ code like:

```
#include <pcl/filters>
```

**Progress**

I have followed the tutorial: https://gist.github.com/IgniparousTempest/ce5fadbe742526d10d6bdbf15c3a3fe7#file-ubuntu_16-06_pcl_1-8-0_install-sh

The commands ran successfully, and the library (both .cpp and .h files) are currently at: `~/Documents/pcl`.

**What should I do next?**

What do i need to do with this library now?

I am fairly new to installing C++ libraries like this is Linux, in particular using cmake and make commands.

I previously installed pcl 1.7 using the terminal command `sudo apt-get install libpcl-all`.This placed header files in `/usr/include/pcl-1.7/`. Where did the corresponding .cpp files go? I could not locate them using the bash command `$ locate generic_pcl_filename.cpp`

I also wonder whether I should place the pcl 1.8 folder in the `/usr/include` directory, but this seems wrong as the folder also contains .cpp files.

Any advice and information on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `/usr/local/include` may be a better place. [https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/please-difference-between-usr-include-and-usr-local-include-818767/](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/please-difference-between-usr-include-and-usr-local-include-818767/)

Comment: Don't use this kind of scripts to install libraries. If something gets wrong in the middle of the script you will have troubles to investigate why. Just compile this library normally and install it in the default path (which in linux systems is `/usr/local` and yes you will be able to include headers from this location). In case you don't know, the standard procedure in case of cmake projects is: `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..` , `make`, `sudo make install`

Comment: cpp files do not get installed. so files or executable files get installed, usually.

Comment: The last command in the script - `sudo make install` - **installs** PCL. You may repeat this command and it will print which exact (destination) files has been installed. For being able to include the header via `#include <pcl/filters>` you need to set **include directories** appropriately. "What should I do next?", "What do i need to do with this library now?" - Such a vague question.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks. Does it matter where I place the library when running these commands?  and is there a way to specify where I want the library installed, i.e. /usr/ or /usr/local?

Comment: @chrispduck, doesn't matter, I keep my libraries sources in `$HOME/Libs`, but it is a personal choice. To change the install directory to `/usr` you can invoke cmake like this: `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I install a built C++ library to /usr/include?

Usually, by using a package manager. What the package manager does is simply copy the header files under that directory. Besides that, it also keeps track of which files belong to which installed package.

If you want to install a library outside of the context of the package manager, then you should use /usr/local/include instead because /usr/include is conventionally reserved to the package manager. The copying can be done with `cp` although libraries often typically come with a build system that has knowledge of the system conventions and installing can be as simple as `make install` for example. The library should document how it should be installed.

> I previously installed ... using the terminal command sudo apt-get install ...This placed header files in /usr/include/pcl-1.7/. Where did the corresponding .cpp files go?

The maintainer who created the apt package compiled the cpp files. The package doesn't contain the source, but instead the compiled library (whether in form of archived object files, or a dynamically loadable shared library).